# What are the fonts used in the none theme of PlantUML?

Tags: fonts, themes, plantuml

I want to reproduce the fonts used in the PlantUML [*none* theme](https://the-lum.github.io/puml-themes-gallery/#none). I need this to make graphics generated with another tool consistent with my PlantUML diagrams.

I tried looking at the [`/themes` in PlantUML's GitHub repository](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/tree/master/themes) but the fonts for the [*none* theme](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/master/themes/puml-theme-_none_.puml) aren't explicitly coded and I can't figure out what they are.

In other words, what are the fonts used in the type icons (e.g. `C` for Class, `I` for Interface, etc..), labels and fields in the class diagram for the default *none* theme as shown below?

[image: class diagram of none theme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-svg` output, I find

```
font-family="sans-serif"
```

This is probably rendered using an *Arial* font.
But there are other sans-serif fonts like *Helvetica* and *Calibri*.

Comment: [This thread on the PlantUML forums](https://forum.plantuml.net/6114/default-font-used) says the default Java font  "SansSerif" is used which is system dependent.